# What is the best folder structure for unit and functional tests using Symfony 4?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, symfony4

What is the best folder structure to store unit and functional tests using Symfony 4?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/tests.html

Comment: and where is described the folder structure?

Answer (score 2):

According to official Symfony page https://symfony.com/download, they provide a Symfony Demo application with best practices.

**Description:**
Symfony Demo application, The best Symfony learning resource and the reference to develop applications following the official best practices.

**Symfony - Official Repository:**
https://github.com/symfony/demo

If you check the repository, tests are located in `/demo/tests/`

```
/demo/tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php

/demo/tests/Controller/BlogControllerTest.php

/demo/tests/Command/AddUserCommandTest.php

/demo/tests/Utils/ValidatorTest.php
```

Comment: there are very poor examples, what if I want to separate unit, functional and integration tests ?